# how to compare objects values in 2 identical lists in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have two collections in mongo db that hold reports, in report there is list matches, so what i want is to run on production reports and for ech one check in staging reports and check that if the matches are the same length if the personId and addressId are also the same...

is there a a good way to do this?

i came up with something like this:

```
db.production_reports.find({}).forEach((prodRep)=> { 
      db.reports.find({_id: prodRep._id}).forEach((stagingRep)=> { 
         if (prodRep.matches.length == stagingRep.matches.length) {
             prodRep.matches.forEach((match)=> {
                 var res = stagingRep.matches.filter(element => element.personId == match.personId && element.addressId == match.addressId);
                 if (res) {
                     print("yay")
                 } else {
                     print("nay")
                 }
             });
         }
      });
});
```

i want for each report the script to tell me "yes, all matches equal", or print the reportId that have non equal matches

thanks

Comment: That piece of code is working, right? But you want to make it more clear

Comment: First of all I would think of a soluce based on cursor. Your actual soluce will crash on huge collections.

Comment: @GMaiolo no, its printing yay/nay for when it found match but i want the script to tell me "yes, all equale", or print the reportId that have non equal matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would draft something like this :

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  const data = {
    // contains an array of _id of missing production_reports
    missing: [],
    different: [],
  };

  // Look at each entry in production_reports
  db.production_reports.find({})
    .cursor()
    .eachAsync(async (x) => {
      // get the similar data on reports
       const copy = await db.reports.find({
         _id: x._id,
       });

       // If the data doesn't exists into reports
       if (!copy || !copy.length) {
          data.missing.push(x._id);

          return;
       }

       // If it exists, compare the inner values

       // if the size isn't the same, it's obviously different
       if (x.matches.length !== copy.length) {
         data.different.push(x._id);

         return;
       }

       // Check every element of match one by one
       if (x.matches.some(y => !copy.matches.some(z => z.personId === y.personId))) {
          data.different.push(x._id);
       }
    }, {
      // How many items do we look at same time
      parallel: 250,
    }, () => {
      // When we are done processing all items
      resolve(data);
    });
});
```

NOTE : It won't give you missing documents that exists in reports but not in production_reports